# Prove that $supp\, T=\{(x,-x); \, x \in \mathbb R\}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let denote by $T$ the distribution of order $0$ on $\mathbb R$ given by 
$$ T(\phi) = \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x,-x) dx.$$
How can prove that the support of $T$ is $supp\, T=D:=\{(x,-x); \, x \in \mathbb R\}$ ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean that $T$ is a distribution on $\Bbb R^2$.

Any $\phi$ with support not meeting $D$ is annihilated by $T$,
so supp$\,T$ is a closed subset of $D$. Let $(x,-x)\in D$ and $U$
an open neighbourhood of $x$. Taking $\phi$ to be a bump function centred
at $(x,-x)$ with arbitrarily support in $U$ shows that $(x,-x)$ is not
in the support of $T$.